# What does 'by the water' mean?

Tags: meaning, lyrics

I am newbie here have been learning English since few months I recently heard a song 'Rockabay' ([Google Play lyrics](https://play.google.com/music/preview/T54wiubwc3kxijwfugyhwld45zy?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-lyrics)) and couldn't get the meaning of '**By the water**' in this context.

> She works the night, by the water
>   She's gonna stress, so far away from her father's daughter
>   She just wants a life for her baby
>   All on her own, no one will come
>   She's got to save him (daily struggle)

Comment: You would have to ask the songwriter for a definitive answer. I could be a reference to the fact that prostitutes work at night, and some hang out near docks (by the water) because sailors are their clients.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, like many song lyrics, it's not possible to work out exactly what the writer meant.

Comment: "By the water" means just that.  There is no need for it to be metaphorical.  The songwriter just wanted to find a rhyme with "daughter".

Comment: Well, that was silly. It's an ESL student asking about what words mean. Of course it's on topic. They just didn't understand that *by* can mean *beside* as well as *through using*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to know for sure the exact meaning of parts of song texts, they are often symbolic and open to multiple interpretations.

The first thing that comes to my mind, however is the following:

*She works the night* indicates she does the kind of job that is performed outside the normal working hours, and by implication, not the most honourable job.

*By the water* indicates the presence of water, possibly the sea, and by the sea, one of the places where a woman could work at night would be a harbour, working as a prostitute for the seaman that come ashore there.

Part of this interpretation is based on the fact that prostitution is, in my experience, quite a common way to describe how hard life is for a person, especially a woman.

That said, these lyrics are full of "interesting" twists, like "so far away from her father's daughter". Her father's daughter is she, herself (in which case I guess this describes some out-of-body-experience, like an LSD-trip), or her sister - in which case this is a very wordy way to say "sister".

Answer (score 3):

I think, **"by the water"** in that sentences is the synonym of "next to the lake or pond, sea,...!

I'm a new leaner too! I think this answer can help you!